# Update live USB distro?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, live-usb, live-environment

I have Lubuntu 14.04 (and Ubuntu 14.04) on a pair of USB disks created by writing the img files to USB using dd on Mac OS X.

Unfortunately these systems both have some known bugs (that have since been corrected) and lack certain important drivers for my system (which I have located online).

How can I make the USB disks writable and how do I update the distribution upon them as one may do for a locally-installed system?

And if I later proceed to install from these USB sticks onto a hard-drive, will they ‘carry’ the package and driver updates with them or will I have to start from scratch again? (I seem to remember from my ancient Windows XP days that such procedures were referred to as ’slipstreaming’ or somesuch on that side of the fence.)

(No, I did not create a persistence partition when I created the sticks, because from Mac clearly that isn’t an option. And anyway, as I imperfectly understand it, the persistence partition is for user files and not for the modification of the system.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## You need persistence.

Persistence is not only for user files but also for updates.

## You can create persistence on a Mac

Download [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and create the liveUSB with it.

## Installation doesn't replicate updates

When you use the liveUSB to install Ubuntu, it will not install the updates done in the live system.

Comment: So I create a USB stick with Persistence enabled and then I go through an ordinary `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` cycle?

Comment: yes. Or you may use Software Updater.

Comment: I used Unetbootin to create a bootable Lubuntu x86 Live stick and I set 2048 MB for 'Persistance'. Unfortunately when I tried to boot off it all I got was "Missing Operating System".

Comment: I had a similar issue. Instead of the default option in the boot menu, use "Try Ubuntu without installing".

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer i got from Thibaut Lauziere
SAN Engineer / LiLi's Developer:

Nope you can't. That's a restriction of Live USBs. You have to create your key using an already updated ISO.